# Django: How to get the root path of a site in template?

Tags: python, django

I want to design a go back home button for my site and how can I get the root path of my site in the template so I can do something like this:

```
<a href="{{ root_url }}">Go back home</a>
```

Or I should first figure out the path in my views and then pass it to the template to render by some context.
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the proper way here is use the `{% url %}` tag and I'm assuming that you have a root url in your url conf.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^mah_root/$', 'someapp.views.mah_view', name='mah_view'),
```

Then in your template:

```
<a href="{% url mah_view %}">Go back home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, BTW what does name in the url mean?

Comment: It's for naming urls so that you can refer to them more easy. The name I used was just arbitrary so it has no meaning.

Comment: say I have a bunch of blog post all under the path /blog/some_8_digit_number. How can I refer them by the name?

Comment: your `urls.py` would have to look like this `url(r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$', 'someapp.views.blog_detail_view', name='blog_detail'),`. Your view `def blog_detail_view(request, blog_id):` and your template `{% url blog_detail blog_id %}` where blog_id would be the 8 digits.

Comment: Also note that, since Django 1.5, you need to put the URL 'name' in quotes, like this: `{% url 'mah_view' %}` to distinguish it from a variable of the same name.

Answer (score 15):

You should be able to access the [get_host()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) method of the request:

```
<a href="http://{{ request.get_host() }}">Go back home</a>
```

Though you could probably also do:

```
<a href="/">Go back home</a>
```

Comment: Interesting idea. However since Home page does not have to be `/` (it might be for example `/home`) then I think that limelights' solution is better.

Answer (score 9):

I found a trick, Use this tag:
 `{{ HTTP_HOST }}`

you could do:

```
<a href="{{ HTTP_HOST }}"> back home <a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{ HTTP_HOST }}/what_you_want"> back home <a>
```

Answer (score 3):

this is what i did:

in urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='landing.html'), name='landing')
]
```

then, in whatever view:

```
<a href="{% url 'landing' %}">Site Title</a>
```

this will resolve to localhost:8000/ or site.domain.com/ whichever you are using, when you click the link

Answer (score 1):

Referring to standard Django example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Then template code:

```
href="{% url 'index' %}"
```

will also work.