# Get URL and port number from view

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

Is there a way of grabbing a subset of the URL in Django views.py?

I have tried `request.build_absolute_uri()` but that captures slightly more than I want.

E.G.
If the URL was `http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/new` I would like to get `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Instead I end up getting the entire URL, with the page names.

I am wondering if there is a rootURL function in Django or something similar maybe?

Comment: Here are a few [different approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009691/django-how-to-get-the-root-path-of-a-site-in-template) in a previous answer  

If you want to use a function it would probably be the [get_host()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) function

Comment: Great thanks! Care to construct this as an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question has a few approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009691/django-how-to-get-the-root-path-of-a-site-in-template) which are:

Using request.get_host(),

```
<a href="http://{{ request.get_host() }}">Go back home</a>
```

Using href='/',

```
<a href="/">Go back home</a>
```

Or Using the root url defined in your url conf.

```
url(r'^mah_root/$', 'someapp.views.mah_view', name='mah_view'),
```

Then in your template:

```
<a href="{% url mah_view %}">Go back home</a>
```