# jquery id is matched but won't work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have python/django app, need search engine and for search engine I'm using the power of jquery. I'm still very new to Jquery(actually whole Javascript) but I think this seems right to, I'm not sure why this won't work.

so  I have this code:

```
 <li class="nav-header">search for community</li>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />

      <ul id="search-results">

      </ul>
```

I have input id search. and another id search-results. 
then I have this javascript file.

```
$(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/search/",
            data: { 
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});();

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

I'm matching id search here. using keyup function. Is it because the function is wrong?It's very unlikely because the whole thing works fine. by whole thing , I mean the functionality of searching works here http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/ which has search.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Search</h2>

    <form method="get" action=".">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        {% if query %}
            <h3>Results</h3>

            {% for result in page.object_list %}
                <p>
                    <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.name }}</a>
                </p>
            {% empty %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
                <div>
                    {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                    |
                    {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
        {% endif %}
    </form>

{%endblock%}
```

I'm trying to use what works in search.html to work in a search bar in index.html and with Jquery keyup function. 
can you please tell why I can't use jquery function that has matched id?

For detail: this is how my code works 
Inside urls.py 
I have `url(r'^search/$',include('haystack.urls')),`
 and other haystack settings.
then inside views.py

```
def search_titles(request):
    categories = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.POST.get('search_text', ''))            

    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html', {'categories' : categories
        })
```

for ajax_search.html

```
{% if categories.count > 0 %}

{% for category in categories %}
    <li><a href="/category/{{post.category}}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}

<li>None to show!</li>

{% endif %}
```

The problem is occuring from ajax I'm almost sure

Comment: `});();`  <-- That is wrong...

Comment: yeah, remove this guy `();`

Comment: @epascarello thanks but I get http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static_in_pro/our_static/js/ajax.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: @Pamblam thanks but I get http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static_in_pro/our_static/js/ajax.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: @lip123809 - your path is wrong. i can't tell you the correct path cus i can't see your filesystem. you're on your own there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just practicing AJAX, your approach is ok, but jQuery has [a neat method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to do this..

```
$(function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
            $('#search-results').load("/search/", { 
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I'm having a very weird problem.  I have other javascript files rendering fine but this one. I set them all same but I only get Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) from this. Is there a way to check why with console do you know?

Comment: you are using a relative path. unless both scripts are in the same directory, they cant be exactly the same.

Comment: every time I type some thing, on console GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static_in_pro/our_static/js/ajax.js?_=1452646768611 404 (NOT FOUND) shows up, if I type more, more of this comes out

Comment: find the path in your browser first, then just copy the full path from the browser.

Comment: I have vote.js and ajax.js in same js folder, <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/vote.js' %}"></script> this works so I did <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ajax.js' %}"></script>
but ajax.js isn't working. It kinda works because every time I type, something  messed up is coming up and more importantly that error in console which I think is a hint

Comment: something shows up when I write something on search bar, but still gets the same error. does this mean the path is still wrong?

Comment: yeah, depends on what console you're using. some say net some say network

Comment: if you're using the full path and the same path works on the other script then the path should be right. is it still a 404? whats the error?

Comment: no it's not 404 anymore it says GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static_in_pro/our_static/js/ajax.js

Comment: what does it say in the response tab?

Comment: by response ta b do you mean my search bar?

Comment: also, what path do you put in your browser when you view this (the non-working) page?

Comment: on console I get GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static_in_pro/our_static/js/ajax.js 
127.0.0.1/:318 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ 404 (NOT FOUND) and on search bar I get the content on my search.html

Comment: can you screenshot your console for me and put in in imgur or something? i'm not sure what kind of console you're looking at.

Comment: first of all, it doesn't make any sense to make an ajax call to a js file. you said it wasn't a 404 anymore then you said it was. contradicting infomation here...

Comment: on second image, when I write something other contents are coming out

Comment: hello it says user needs to be logged in, and it won't let me login

Comment: ok, the only other thing i can think of, zip up your entire webroot and send it to pivozwne@sharklasers.com. that's all i got

Comment: you can go to here, https://github.com/lip365/ebagu0.2 if it's more convenience for you. I have very messy python code tho

Comment: ok help me out. which is the working and which is the not working scripts

Comment: https://github.com/lip365/ebagu0.2/blob/master/rclone/static_in_pro/our_static/js/ajax.js

Comment: this is causing the problem

Comment: you're not giving me enough information. I need to see the real paths. if you want to send me your webroot i'll look at it otherwise there's really not much else i can tell you. 404 means the browser can't find the location you gave it. in other words, the path is wrong.

Comment: ok I don't know this, I've tried bunch of things but still stuck...please take a look at my code... do you have gmail?we can chat there too

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in developer tools(chrome)? If you go to Network tab, then click on XHR, you will get all the ajax requests for the current page.

Now, when you find your request, click it and go to "Response". If HTTP code 20x or 304 is used, you're getting a proper response back. If not, the server doesn't know how to handle your request(404) or a server error occured(500).

If you're getting a proper response back, try adding a console.log inside that callback. You should see whatever your script is returning.

Ajax is never to blame, ajax is just the method for hiding client > server communication. It's either how the client side script is handling things or how the server side script is handling things.

Comment: that means I didn't set the path for javascript file right,,? I'm assuming

Comment: I get http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static_in_pro/our_static/js/ajax.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) it means I didn't set the path correctly right?

Comment: Do note that 127.0.0.1 is your local computer and nobody will be able to see that. To check what path the 404 is coming from, right click a row and choose *open in new tab*. And yes, the path probably is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this hasn't been resolved yet.

The way I usually do this is by setting the global site root just before loading the JS file or by [generating an url for your search url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009691/django-how-to-get-the-root-path-of-a-site-in-template). Then in your javascript file, just use the global variable that you set earlier. I don't know django so code below could have errors.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var ROOT= {{ build_absolute_uri('/')|escapejs }};</script>
<script src='{% url search_script %}'></script>
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, I think that's what I did tho